# ReactJs: Appending list item from socket input

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am using socket io to create a chat app. Each time I receive a message from client side inside componentDidMount, I have set a state to the incoming message. How can I populate this message to a list item and keep the process going?

Comment: Will you please elaborate a bit more? Cause your current question statement is not showing your problem.

Comment: Hi, mY problem is that... i am not able to append every incoming message to a new list item. Since i am storing the incoming message on to a state, if i render it to a list , the same li gets updated on every message.I am new to react.I want to store the messages on new li's on every new message.Hope u got my problem.

Comment: Please post your code as your comment doesn't make sense, sounds like you're doing something strange